# reading tiff images on windows

Tags: windows, image, visual-studio-2008, file-io, tiff

I want to read tiff images in C (windows 64 bit, visual studio 2008). Is there a place where I can get compiled library for libtiff 64bit? The one available at http://bigtiff.org/libtiff.lib-4.1.zip, is compiled for 32 bits and throws link errors when used for 64 bit project.

I am willing to explore other(simple) libraries for reading 16 bit TIFF images in the setup mentioned.

Comment: TIFF isn't a simple format so you're unlikely to find a simple library for it. You should be able to recompile `libtiff` yourself though.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by compiling libtiff using visual studio 2008, download libtiff-4.1 from http://bigtiff.org/libtiff-4.1.zip, open libtiff.vcproj and change the include folders in visual studio 2008(it is incorrect in the setup), and compile for 64 bits, once you have libtiff compiled, it can be used a library with the header files for reading tiff images